# Does template hierarchy work the same in magento as child themes do in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, magento

I am new to magento and i'm confused about themes. I bought a theme and got it installed and now i need to make some changes.

**In wordpress** ... ( which i am used to) what i would do at this point is to make a child theme ( which is essentially one css file with a tiny bit of code in it ) .... and any changes in that child theme would override the parent theme **in that area only** while the parent theme would govern everything else, the advantage being that when it comes to updating the theme i dont need to maintain a "hacks list" and reimpliment all my modifications.

However the people who sold me the theme make no mention of anything like this, and suggest simply editing the theme itself, despite the fact that magento has a "theme hierarchy"

So can anyone explain this to me, Does template hierarchy work the same in magento as child themes do in wordpress... and if not what is the procdeure for updating the theme vis a vis keeping the theme alterations made by the site developer from the original downloaded version

Comment: Does their theme reside in a separate package? Put another way, does it reside in `app/design/frontend/default` or in `app/design/frontend/theirpackagename`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Does template hierarchy work the same in magento as child themes do in wordpress*

No.

*what is the procedure for updating the theme vis a vis keeping the theme alterations made by the site developer from the original downloaded version*

Starting from the bottom, Magento (post 1.4.1.1) has a theme folder at

```
app/design/frontend/base/default
```

This is the **final** place Magento will look for any particular template file. Only people who know why they'd want to edit/add files in there should edit or add files in there.  And even most of them shouldn't.

Next up (and this is confusing, so pay attention, and don't feel bad if you're confused), Magento has the concept of a **default** theme.  This is a theme name you configure in

```
System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes -> Default Theme
```

This default folder is where you can put your base theme.  If you entered the value `theirtheme`, Magento would look for theme template and layout files in

```
app/design/frontend/default/theirtheme/template
app/design/frontend/default/theirtheme/layout
```

Next up, themes are made up of

- Layout XML files
- Templates
- Translation files
- "Skin" files (which live outside the app/design hierarchy)

Each of these has a configuration area in

```
System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes
```

So, let's say you configured the **Templates** config value with the value `mytheme`, and your **Default** was set, as above, to `theirtheme`.  Magento would first look for phtml template files in

```
app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/path/to/file.phtml
```

If it didn't find one there, it would look to the default theme that you configured

```
app/design/frontend/default/theirtheme/template/path/to/file.phtml
```

Finally, if it didn't find one in either place, it check one last time in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/path/to/file.phtml
```

So, it sounds like what you want to do is make the theme you downloaded your default theme, and then configure a custom folders where you can add your changes.

### Other Notes

The word `frontend` in

```
app/design/frontend
```

is a **area**.  An area roughly corresponds to a single web application.  The frontend area is the shopping cart, the `adminhtml` area is the Admin Console.

The first `default` in

```
app/design/frontend/default
```

is the **Design Package** folder.  A design package is a collection of themes. This often causes confusion, since the default package has nothing to do with the default theme, but they share the same, um, default name.

Finally, w/r/t what your theme vendor told you, Magento's still a young platform and it's in flux, and the best practices for these sorts of things are still sorting themselves out.  It's often going to be up to you to decide the best way to take advantage of Magento's various systems.

Comment: thanks, i am halfway through those examples; can I ask,it seems like hierarchy in Magento serves 2 purposes, one being to defer to a different theme if a file is accidental missing but the second being that i can deliberately add "custom folder" as you call it higher in the hierarchy and it takes over from files underneath in the hierarchy changing the output if found and not if not....correct ? so that if i put a single css file in my custom folder containing just one single line eg body{background:red} then that one line would take precedence over any body{background:} below in the hierarchy

Comment: The theme system simple controls which particular files get loaded. It's neutral the the application of things like CSS cascading rules.

Comment: according to magento if i want to create a custom theme i should just copy the file(s) i need to change (being careful to preserve the directory structure) I tried this and it worked perfectly with the main styles.css file; however what i cant understand is that it stopped displaying the images referenced in that css file .... if the magento website was correct then i should be able to create a custom theme using only a css file in the correct directory structure but it seems i also have to copy over the image files referenced by that css file - could you comment? thanks again for your advice

Comment: You're a professional CSS developer.  Look at what Magento's doing and figure it out.

Comment: ??? sorry i didnt mean to be lazy - i already spent hours at it - magento's documentation is full of hard to follow slightly bad english ( in my opinion ) .... dont worry though i will figure it out and thanks again for all your invaluable help

Comment: from what i can see it seems that while i can put replacement images and files into my custom theme i cant do the same with images which have been referenced in the css  file because (in my theme) the images are referenced relatively eg url(../images/image.gif) A.O.T. something that would allow magento to figure out where the original file is. It seems we have to copy all the images referenced by any file as well as the file; which will make theme updates overly complicated ..... i'm no expert in this type of coding so i cant say whether it would be possible to do without using the full url

Comment: for anyone reading this in the future correct me if i'm wrong but i think the best answer is to change all the relative urls from ../images to ../../parent_theme/images

Comment: This is definitely the way to go! If you've purchased a theme, this leaves room for updates from the purchased theme's developers, while leaving your customizations alone.